# Double for loop in a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with keys from 1 to N. I would like to go through this dictionary with a double for loop so that I don't take two elements at the same time (k goes from 1 to N-1 and j from k+1 to N). I need to this efficiently as I will have to repeat this operation. Is there anyway to do a dictionary comprehension so as to go through the keys as: k goes from 1 to N-1 and j from k+1 to N?

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: Doing what you want to do may seem to work but is extremely dangerous as dictionaries are not ordered. It doesn't guarantee the order of its elements. It seems you are not using the right data structure. If you look for a sequence of ordered elements accessible through their position, you need a list.

Comment: You may be looking for `itertools.product`, but your question is rather vague.

Comment: I don't choose the format of my input data eventhough I agree it should be a list. What I want to do is go through all the couples of objects in the dictionary and compute the distance between them. The reason I think a double loop would be inefficient is that I don't want to compare a couple twice since I have a lot of them and it would waste computation time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the order of the keys don't matter, you can do it like this

```
my_dict = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4}

from itertools import combinations
for key1, key2 in combinations(my_dict.keys(), r = 2):
    print key1, key2
```

**Output**

```
a c
a b
a d
c b
c d
b d
```

Answer (score 1):

By your description, it sounds like you're trying to access the upper triangle of (what should be) an array, so you can use numpy's `triu`(http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.triu.html).

As others have said, using a dictionary is probably not the best choice.

Answer (score 1):

On **"What I want to do is go through all the couples of objects in the dictionary and compute the distance between them"**

You can use numpy broadcasting to calculate the distances, it's fast:

```
In [175]: locs=np.array([1,2,4,6])

In [176]: np.abs(locs[:, None]-locs)
Out[176]: 
array([[0, 1, 3, 5],
       [1, 0, 2, 4],
       [3, 2, 0, 2],
       [5, 4, 2, 0]])
```

and you can use the index e.g., `locs[0][3]` to get distance between element 0 and element 3 directly.